# Django channels with Python background tasks

Tags: django, multithreading, sockets, django-channels, telnetlib

I am writing a Python based application (CLI Back End) which does telnet to some network components and gets some data. It saves the data in SQLite db.

For this application I am writing Django based frond end. Which will start the CLI app and monitor it. For communication between the CLI App and Django I am not able to decide what to use. I read somewhere on net that Django channels can be used in this problem.

I have no idea about what Django channel is and what it does. I need to come up with a tool for this CLI and Django communication.

Comment: Why not just connect to SQLite from the Django app? You can record your monitoring information in there.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate [of your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435647/controlling-python-program-from-django-front-end).

Comment: Yes it is halfer.. I posted the other question few days back. At that time i have no idea about channels n all. moreover i dint get any response there...

Comment: For using the sqlite directly in django app.. The background scripts will not only serve the data. I need to implement some mechanism to check the running status of back end scipts too..